# Как помножить на определённое число некоторые числа в списке

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

У меня есть список

```
[7, 100, 83, 1000, 9, 100, 19]
```

Мне нужно умножить на сто только те числа, после которых идёт число сто. Должно получится вот-так:

```
[700, 83, 1000, 900, 19]
```

Пытаюсь сделать через такой код:

```
    stack2 = []
i = 1
while i < len(stack):
    if stack[i] == 100:
        stack2.append(stack[i-1]*100)
    elif len(stack) == 2 and i == len(stack)-1:  # Гдето здесь ошибка есть
        stack2.append(stack[i-1])
        stack2.append(stack[i])
    elif i == len(stack)-1:
        stack2.append(stack[i])
    elif stack[i-1] != 100:
        stack2.append(stack[i-1])
    i += 1
```

Подскажите как лучше это сделать.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Умножать надо только парами? Что если будет так `[7, 100, 100]`?

Comment: *Мне нужно умножить на сто только те цифры, после которых идёт цифра сто.* Я вижу совсем иное - если в смежной паре второе значение 100, заменить эту пару на их произведение. PS. Это не цифры, это числа.

Comment: *# Гдето здесь ошибка есть* Это ошибка в логике. Вот нахрена проверять условия для ПОСЛЕДНЕГО элемента? после него элементов нет, то есть заведомо после него нет элемента со значением 100...

Comment: Не перестаю удивляться авторам, которые задают вопрос и тут же теряются. Ответ видать не так уж и нужен.

Comment: Akina, да это пара чисел, которые нужно перемножить.

Answer (score 3):

```
from functools import reduce

data = [7, 100, 83, 1000, 9, 100, 19]

reduce(lambda acc, val: acc[:-1] + [acc[-1] * val] if val == 100 and len(acc) else acc + [val], data, [])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
x = [7, 100, 83, 1000, 9, 100, 19]

for value, index in zip(reversed(x[1:]), range(len(x) - 1, 0, -1)):
    if (value == 100):
        x[index - 1] *= x.pop(index)

print(x)  # [700, 83, 1000, 900, 19]
```

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант:

```
lst = [7, 100, 83, 1000, 9, 100, 19]
lst2 = []
for i in range(len(lst)):
    if lst[i] == 100:
        continue
    if i != len(lst) - 1:
        if lst[i+1] == 100:
            lst2.append(lst[i] * 100)
        else:
            lst2.append(lst[i])
    else:
        lst2.append(lst[i])
print(lst2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант **#slippyk**, только используем enumerate:

```
l = [7, 100, 83, 1000, 9, 100, 19]

for i, v in enumerate(l):
    if v == 100:
       l[i-1] *= l.pop(i)

print(l) # [700, 83, 1000, 900, 19]
```